# How do I require that a user hit <RETURN>, when editing a Trait value, before change notifications are sent out?

Tags: enthought, traitsui

I find myself waiting for the GUI of my Traits/UI application to update, with each backspace and/or digit entry in a particular field. How can I get the Traits/UI notification system to wait until I press RETURN before it sends out change notifications?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885345/traitsui-prevent-txt-box-from-realtime-updating/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `auto_set` and `enter_set` attributes of a `TextEditor`.  `auto_set=False` stops updating the trait on every keystroke, and `enter_set=True` causes it to update on <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  See [here](http://docs.enthought.com/traitsui/traitsui_user_manual/factories_basic.html#texteditor) for docs.

For example:
    from traits.api import HasTraits, Str
    from traitsui.api import View, TextEditor, Group, Item

```
class Foo(HasTraits):
    my_str = Str()

    traits_view = View(
        Item('my_str',
            style='custom',
            editor=TextEditor(
                auto_set=False,
                enter_set=True,
                ),
        ),
        Item('my_str',
            style='readonly'
        ),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = Foo()
    f.configure_traits()
```

[image]